# Find files that end with number

Tags: find, filenames, wildcards, patterns

Im trying to make some backup script as the log files get bigger and bigger. What i have is coping the current file, (for example `secure` file in `/var/log/`) and remove the content from that file. But there are some files with the name like: `secure.1`, `secure.2` and all this i like to count them, and if the number is bigger then `2` to archive them all. I can't find the method to find this files or count them. The first think that come up to me was:

```
find /var/log/ -name *.1 | wc -l
```

and this will always print `1` as there is one file `secure.1`. How can i count like in for loop where i can specified a range of numbers like `{1..5}` or similar. Is there a way to separate this files and make them as one and them backup or delete or what ever ... or first of all how can i find all this numbers that ends up with number.

Comment: Did you forget to quote the wildcard? `find /var/log/ -name '*.1' ...`

Comment: I think your should check `logrotate` for your purpose.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With simple `-name`:

```
find /var/log -name '*.[2-9]'
```

or for any digit:

```
find /var/log -name '*.[[:digit:]]'
```

or if other chars are possible after digit:

```
find /var/log -name '*.[2-9]*'
```

Comment: how to find those that ONLY contain digit in their name?

Answer (score 3):

To find the filenames which ends with a number ranges from `.` [1 to 5].

```
find /var/log/ -type f -regextype sed -regex ".*\.[1-5]$"
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just...

```
for log in /var/log/*.[1-5]
do whatever to "$log"
done
```

You don't need `find` as far as I can tell - the shell uses the same globs it does in `-name`. And if all of the files are in a single directory... Of course, if there are subdirectories you're also interested in then `find` could be beneficial - walking trees in the shell can be a headache.